Can QueryPerformanceCounter return negative timestamps?
In our software, we use QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency. We were under the impression that QueryPerformanceCounter could return negative, but increasing, timestamps.
However, some searching online (and some chatting with ChatGPT) suggests that on Windows, getting negative timestamps from the high-performance timer, even if monotonically increasing, is a sign of a problem in the system, perhaps even a BIOS configuration issue.
For example, see the following discussions:
https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/1167
QueryPerformanceCounter and weird results
https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/97413-queryperformancefrequency-negative-value.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/programs-queryperformancecounter-function-perform-poorly
I also saw some discussion that you could get negative timestamps when combining the output of QueryPerformanceCounter with the output of QueryPerformanceFrequency, if QueryPerformanceFrequency had an uncaught exception.
My question is:
-> Is any of this true?
Many thanks and best wishes,
Rob
==========================================================
I tried searching the relevant resources, but was not able to find a definitive "yes" or "no" answer.

I estimate that QueryPerformanceCounter which on a PC is RDTSC in disguise on a modern CPU clocked at ~4GHz could become negative after a continuous runtime of ~65 years (~2x10^9 s).  You would have to store it incorrectly in a signed long long. I have never seen it be anything other than monotonically increasing on the same core.
